# How can I use a Bing Javascript Map in server-side Blazor?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm trying to use the [Bing JavaScript Map control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/getting-started/) in a new (3.0.0-preview6.19307.2) [Blazor server-side application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.0).  I have had this working on earlier versions of Blazor and in a client-side application.

The [current Blazor JavaScript interop guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interop?view=aspnetcore-3.0) does not suggest that any new steps are required but when I add the following section in the body of  **_Hosts.cshtml** and call the *createMap* function I get an error saying

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Browser.Rendering.RemoteRenderer:
>
> Warning: Unhandled exception rendering component: 'Microsoft' is not
>   defined
>
> ReferenceError: 'Microsoft' is not defined at window.createMap (https://localhost:44372/:79:9)

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol"></script>

   <script>

    var map = null;
    window.createMap = (data) => {
        if (map != null)
            return;
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap',
            {
                credentials: '... my credentials ...',
                zoom: 1
            }
        );
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.HeatMap');
        return ;
    };
    </script>
```

This code *does* work correctly when placed in the index.html of an equivalent client-size Blazor project so I'm guessing some extra step is required to export the map into the Microsoft name-space.  Can anyone suggest what I am missing?

Comment: You could try putting the script tag that references the library in the head of the document - I'm guessing here because you haven't specified where it is currently.

Comment: thanks - it's currently in the body but I've tried it in the head as well and got the same error.

Comment: So, when the page has loaded, can you check the browser console for errors? Also check in the browser console if you start typing "window.Mic" does Microsoft appear in the autocomplete?

Comment: Actually - thinking about the error - you are calling "createMap" somewhere in your code - where?

Comment: Actually checking the browser console was an excellent suggestion and revealed this warning... "SEC7111: [Mixed-Content] The origin 'https://localhost:44372' was loaded in a secure context but tried to load an insecure script resource at 'http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol'."  Changing the script source for bing.com to httpS from http solved the problem and the map now renders correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question after help from **Mister Magoo**…

The answer in this particular case appears to be that the Blazore server-side model requires an HTTP**S** (not HTTP) connection to the bing maps control.